# Completion reducing to localization on Noetherian rings

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

It is quite easy to show that if $A$ is a Dedekind domain and $\mathfrak{p}\in \operatorname{Spec} A$, then if $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is the completion of $A$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ and $A_{(\mathfrak{p})}=(A\setminus \mathfrak{p})^{-1}A$ is the localization of $A$ at $\mathfrak{p}$, then $$A_{(\mathfrak{p})}=A_{\mathfrak{p}}\cap K$$ where $K$ is the field of fractions of $A$ (essentially, by using the notion of order at $\mathfrak{p}$ of the elements of $K$). I would like to know if the same equality remains true in more general cases, assuming $A$ to be for example an order in some number field. Without prime factorization available I find the equality not easy to prove, and I wonder if it remains true or if there are contrexamples?

Comment: TeX note: use $\operatorname{Spec} A$ `$\operatorname{Spec} A$`, not $Spec$ $A$ `$Spec$ $A$`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: There is an ambiguity: what is the completion $A_{\mathfrak p}$? There are two possibilities: either take the $\mathfrak p$-adic completion, or first localize at $\mathfrak p$ then complete the local ring. It seems that A.G's answer is taking the former, but the later seems more reasonable. If you take the later, you could start with a local domain, and ask whether it is some sort of intersection of the completion and its fraction field?

Answer (score 1):

No. If $A$ is a complete noetherian local ring, then $A$ is complete for the adic topology defined by any other prime ideal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, actually I was interested in something more specific, like an order in a number field. I should probably have specified better in my question, which I have now modified accordingly

Comment: What I said was that, more generally, the completion at a prime does not determine the localization at that prime. But I do not understand the meaning of the equality that you suggest.

Comment: @Hair80 It does not make sense to modify the question so that an answer is "invalidated".

Comment: That intersection could be interpreted if $A_{\mathfrak p}$ is a domain, or maybe weakened, so that the injective ring map $A\to A_{\mathfrak p}$ (injectivity by Krull's intersection theorem) induces an injective map $K\to Q(A_{\mathfrak p})$ where $Q(\cdots)$ is the total ring of fractions, where the intersection is taken.

Comment: @Z.M  It is not ideal, but it sometimes necessary.

Comment: @Hair80 Sorry if the last comment sounds rude. I wanted to suggest an incremental modification instead of modifying key parts which invalidates existing answers (a consequence is that others who do not know the history do not understand why the existing answer appeared.)

Comment: Yes I understand your point. Also it is true that there is an ambiguity with the expression "localization", by which I mean the p-adic one. Maybe I erase the question and reformulate better

Comment: @Hair80 There is no difference between two completions when $\mathfrak p$ is maximal (and in particular, the nontrivial cases that you are interested in). Note that if you only take the $\mathfrak p$-adic completion, then as in this answer, this already fails for Dedekind domains: you could take $\mathfrak p=0$... A point of localization at $\mathfrak p$ is to make the "residue" a field.